# Adicionar eventos BeforeClick e AfterClick a um botão

Tags: java, android, listener

Criei uma nova classe que herda o componente Button.
Chamarei essa classe de "NovoButton".


Esse NovoButton funcionará como o Button tradicional, mas o evento onClick precisa rodar mais 2 novos listeners:


1. antes do código do onClick;

2. depois do código do onClick.


Podemos dizer que esse NovoButton terá um "OnBeforeClickListener", o tradicional OnClickListener e um "OnAfterClickListener".


Com isso, quando a pessoa clicar, 3 eventos podem ser disparados.


Criei duas interfaces (OnBeforeClickListener e OnAfterClickListener) e essa classe NovoButton as implementa.


A minha dúvida é a seguinte:


Como eu faço para chamar o beforeClick e o afterClick respectivamente antes e depois do evento onClick que o NovoButton herdou do Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando uma View é "clicada" a implementação da classe View chama o método `onClick()` da implementação da interface OnClickListener, indicada através do método `setOnClickListener()`.

Como não é possível saber, de antemão, que o botão vai ser clicado, o método `beforeClick()` tem de ser chamado no método `onClick()`.

Como a implementação do `onClick()` é indicada pelo utilizador da classe, tem de arranjar um modo de fazer que esse código seja executado depois de executar `beforeClick()` e antes de executar `afterClick()`.
Ou seja, ao clicar no botão, o código a ser executado tem de ser implementado por si, de forma a respeitar essa sequência, e não o indicado pelo utilizador, através do método `setOnClickListener()`.

Assim, tem de fazer o *override* do método `setOnClickListener()` de forma a que seja usada a sua implementação do OnClickListener, aquela que executa em sequência `beforeClick()`, `onClick()` e `afterClick()`.

```
private OnClickListener mUserOnClickListener;
private OnClickListener mMyOnClickListener;
private OnBeforeClickListener mOnBeforeClickListener;
private OnAfterClickListener mOnAfterClickListener;

@override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    mUserOnClickListener = l;
    super.setOnClickListener(mMyOnClickListener);
}
```

O método `onClick()` do mMyOnClickListener será qualquer coisa como:

```
@override
public void onClick(View v){
    mOnBeforeClickListener.beforeClick(v);
    mUserOnClickListener.onClick(v);
    mOnAfterClickListener.afterClick(v);
}
```

Não esqueça de verificar se os *listeners* não são nulos.

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo!